# JDBC and Oracle DB : Escape ' (single quote)

Tags: java, jdbc, escaping, quote

Hello this looks like simple but I am having issues here.

Firstly I am using [Statement#executeBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) for executing many UPDATE statements. Each update statements have String value to be updated. These String have " ' " single quote. I have tried adding one more single quote in front of it as per Oracle doc as well adding '\\\' in front of single quote. With the first one, my query gets stuck and does not come out even after 10 minutes.  With second one I get 'batching: ORA-00927: missing equal sign' error.

What is the correct approach?
Note:- I cannot use PreparedStatement to make use of JDBC parameters.

Please help.

Comment: Please expand on why you cannot use PreparedStatements. Attempting to manually build and escape sql leaves you vulnerable to application errors and sql injection attacks.

Comment: I did not know I could use batch update even with PreparedStatement. Went through javadoc and understood it can be done. Thanks for your comments.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [q-quoted strin](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311)g eg  `q'['''''''']'`

This give a following example

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

stmt.addBatch("update tst set txt = q'['''''''']' where id = 1");
stmt.addBatch("update tst set txt = q'['''''''']' where id = 2");
stmt.addBatch("update tst set txt = q'['''''''']' where id = 3");
stmt.addBatch("update tst set txt = q'['''''''']' where id = 4");
stmt.addBatch("update tst set txt = q'['''''''']' where id = 5"); 
// submit a batch of update commands for execution
int[] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

But the **correct** way is to use the prepared statement

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("update tst set txt = ? where id = ?");
5.times { i ->
  stmt.setString(1, "''''''''");
  stmt.setInt(2, i+1);
  stmt.addBatch();
}

// submit a batch of update commands for execution
int[] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Comment: I did not know I could use batch update even with PreparedStatement. Went through javadoc and understood it can be done. Thanks for your comments.!